# Schema for the <project> XML in a Sitecore package

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

Does anyone have the schema that relates to the  XML document that appears in the installer folder of a Sitecore package file?

Especially interested in the format of the **project/Sources/xitems/Entries/x-item** element.

Comment: Have you got the scheme?

Comment: Not in a form that I am able to share publically. Currently working on a packaging open source project that can create sitecore zip and update packages from assets on the file system, i.e. outside of a web context.

Comment: can you share a link if it is opensource?

Comment: @Anton, Will do when I push the code to GitHub, probably around a week away

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That XML file seems to be a representation of the `Sitecore.Install.PackageProject` class, so I tried to generate an XSD from code using serialization on that class.
However, if you use a decompile to take a look at how package building and installation works, you'll find out that Sitecore has written their own serializer for this. 
So I wasn't able to generate a correct XSD with the .NET serializer.

With a decompiler (I use [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/), freeware) you can track down a lot of information about that XML file and how it's being used by Sitecore, but I don´t see a (realistic) way to extract a schema from this. 
If you're going to look into it, look inside `Sitecore.Kernel.dll` and look for the `Sitecore.Install` namespace.

Have you tried asking Sitecore Support? If anyone has this schema, it's them.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I've started pulling an XSD together from classes inside the Sitecore.Install namespace and am in the process of validating this work using some existing package XML files. I'll make some inquiries with support as you suggested to see if they can help.